# COMPOUNDRULE inside SFX

Tags: hunspell, nhunspell

I don't understand why my example doesn't work (maybe it's my mistake?)

I have this aff file

```
FULLSTRIP

COMPOUNDMIN 1

COMPOUNDRULE 1
COMPOUNDRULE AC

SFX B Y 1
SFX B a b/A a
```

This dic file

```
2
a/AB
c/C
```

And my tests are

```
ac
bc
```

The result by running `analyze` is

```
> ac
analyze(ac) =  pa:a st:a pa:c st:c
stem(ac) = ac
> bc
Unknown word.
```

While I expected `bc` to be recognized as `analyze(bc) =  pa:b st:b pa:c st:c`, or something like that.
Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow an affix within a compound you need to set one of the COMPOUNDFLAG flags on the affix rule. However, this does not seem to be compatible with COMPOUNDRULE. From the [man page](https://man.archlinux.org/man/hunspell.5.en):

> Note III: COMPOUNDRULE flags work completely separately from the compounding mechanisms using COMPOUNDFLAG, COMPOUNDBEGIN, etc. compound flags. (Use these flags on different entries for words).

However, since the rule in the question is simple you can substitute it with regular COMPOUNDBEGIN/MIDDLE/END flags.

For the affix permission COMPOUNDPERMITFLAG is a good candidate:

> COMPOUNDPERMITFLAG flag
> Prefixes are allowed at the beginning of compounds, suffixes are allowed at the end of compounds
> by default. Affixes with COMPOUNDPERMITFLAG may be inside of compounds.

Code:

```
FULLSTRIP

COMPOUNDMIN 1

COMPOUNDRULE 1
COMPOUNDRULE AC

COMPOUNDPERMITFLAG A
COMPOUNDBEGIN A
COMPOUNDEND C

SFX B Y 1
SFX B a b/A a
```

Example run:

```
$ hunspell -m -d custom_dictionary
ac
ac  pa:a st:a pa:c
ac  pa:a st:a pa:c st:c

bc
bc  pa:b st:a fl:B pa:c
```

Note that `ac` now has an extra derivation using the BEGIN/END pair.

Comment: thank you!
removing
```
COMPOUNDRULE 1
COMPOUNDRULE AC
```
gives one derivation only

Comment: @MauroT If you want to convert multiple COMPOUNDRULEs to BEGIN/END then a simple solution may be to add a new tag: set a single `COMPOUNDEND E` and tag all `C` and `D` words and suffixes with `E` as well (i.e., `c/CE`, `d/DE`).